# Keep a site fully responsive when changing viewport?

Tags: html, css

So I have a site, and I use developer tools. And view it as iPhone5s view and add media queries in:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
 .example {
  background: red;
 }
}
```

But when I drag my browser I can see all the elements look normal/good. Then they all mess up and cross over one another. Then it hits the mobile view and goes normal again because of my media queries. How do I get the elements to keep in there positions. Like not lose the margins at the side and all that?

I've set alot of elements to

```
position: absolute;
```

And so I can freely move elements about the page is this why?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably. `position: absolute` removes the elements from the normal flow of the document. This will probably make your page less responsive.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a very inflexible and generally non-responsive layout method. There are many other **better** alternatives - See [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You need to add more media queries for tablet and small desktop views so that all the element looks good on window drag. As you have already added media query for mobile, it looks good when it enters mobile view

Comment: Do you add this line between the  <head> </head> tag? 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yeah I've added that in the header @Joci93 and should I change all my position:absolute; to position:relative;? So, when I drag the browser. I need to wait till it breaks out of alignment then add a media query? Because it breaks throughout me moving the browser so i'd be adding media queries in every 10pixels or so?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/790/ I made this for you. This use 4 media queries and it's working well. You need to use lot of these.  @MichaelSnoop